# Bare-Metal TCP/IP stack for BeagleBone?

Tags: tcp, beagleboard, bare-metal, beagleboneblack

I plan to use BeagleBone without any of the Linux Distros but with plain bare-metal code.

So first of all: is there already some example-code available for that? Especially a TCP/IP stack for included Ethernet connection?

Thanks!

Comment: What have you researched about the topic so far?  What is the interface to the ethernet from the processor, etc. (is it a usb to ethernet?  will it require a usb host driver?).  which bare metal stack were you thinking of using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, solved. TI's StarterWare comes with lwip, so everything is there.

Comment: Have you run into any problems with StarterWare and more than 4 active connections?

Comment: @Dave: my software uses one connection exclusively, so no, never tested this